# 3D perspective distortion Python

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

im trying to make my own 3d renderer that works with pygame._sdl2 library and it works but there isnt any perspective distortion, i know i didnt have it implemented in the code below.

i need a way to add perspective distortion (depth, scale by distance etc)

thanks, in advance.

```
@cython.inline
def get_position(length, angle_degrees):
    angle_radians = math.radians(angle_degrees)
    x = length * math.cos(angle_radians)
    y = length * math.sin(angle_radians)
    return (x, y)

import cv2







@cython.inline
def project2d(points, rotation, position,global_rotation,global_position):
    points=numpy.add([[0,0,0]]*len(points),points)
    rotation=numpy.add([0,0,0],rotation)
    position=numpy.add([0,0,0],position)
    global_rotation=numpy.add([0,0,0],global_rotation)
    global_position=numpy.add([0,0,0],global_position)
    points2=[]
    
    
    
    local_center=numpy.mean(numpy.array(points),axis=0)
    local_rotation=numpy.add(rotation,global_rotation)

    @cython.inline
    def rotate(a0,axis=0):
        point2d=[a0[axis-1],a0[axis]]
        center2d=[local_center[axis-1],local_center[axis]]
        local_angle=math.degrees(math.atan2(*numpy.subtract(center2d,point2d)))
        local_distance=abs(math.dist(point2d,center2d))
        
        
        npoint2d=get_position(local_distance,local_angle+local_rotation[axis-1])
        
        a0[axis-1],a0[axis]=reversed(npoint2d)
        return a0
        
    x_rotated_points=map( lambda x: rotate(x,axis=0),points)
    y_rotated_points=map( lambda x: rotate(x,axis=2),x_rotated_points)
    z_rotated_points=map( lambda x: rotate(x,axis=1),y_rotated_points)
    """
    x_rotated_points = numpy.array(list(map(lambda x: rotate(x, axis=0), points))).T
    y_rotated_points = numpy.array(list(map(lambda x: rotate(x, axis=2), x_rotated_points))).T
    z_rotated_points = numpy.array(list(map(lambda x: rotate(x, axis=1), y_rotated_points)))
    
    @cython.inline
    def transpose(a0,axis=0):
        point2d=[a0[axis-1],a0[axis]]
        local_position1=[global_position[axis-1],global_position[axis]]
        local_distance=abs(math.dist(point2d,local_position1))
        local_angle=math.degrees(math.atan2(*numpy.subtract(local_position1,point2d)))
        ndistance=get_position(local_distance,local_angle+local_rotation[axis-1])
        a0[axis-1],a0[axis]=reversed(numpy.add(local_position1,ndistance))
        return a0
     
    x_transposed_points=map( lambda x: transpose(x,axis=0),z_rotated_points)
    y_transposed_points=map( lambda x: transpose(x,axis=2),x_transposed_points)
    z_transposed_points=map( lambda x: transpose(x,axis=1),y_transposed_points)
    """   

    
    return z_rotated_points
```

heres how it looks from the top left
[image]

this is how it looks from the front
[image]